# Why useEffect is not called, when props have changed, render is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have useEffect and I don't understand why useEffect is not called, when props have changed, but render is called. I have something like this, 'block' is object:

```
const { block } = props;

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.focus();
        }
    });
}, []);
```

Thank you for helping! Now, I have next question) My inputRef is null, when block is changed and render is called:

```
const { block } = props;

const inputRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.focus();
        }
    });
}, [block, inputRef]);
...
<SomeComponent
  inputRef={inputRef}
 />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have no parameters on your useEffect. If you pass the second parameter as an empty array, it will only fire when the component is mounted.

[Here is a reference from the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: Of course, thank you a lot! And I want to ask another question. Also I have const inputRef = useRef(null), but this is null when new props come and the component is rendered. (<input inputRef={inputRef}/>), why?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this behavior by passing a `block` property as the second parameter in your `useEffect` function:

```
const { block } = props;

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.focus();
        }
    });
}, [block]);
```

Don't forget that you can pass more properties:

`useEffect(() => {}, [block, otherProperty])`